# how to view a string with tabs and newlines, as it is, in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, server

Here is the string:

```
var str = " /t when i want to do a console.log or a document.write /n more text ";
```

When i want to do a console.log or a document.write I want to see:

"/t when i want to do a console.log or a document.write /n more text"

**AND NOT**

```
"    when i want to do a console.log or a document.write 
more text"
```

REASON ? Because the string comes from a server and its formatted with tabs and newlines and it needs to be tokenized for useful puprposes and if I do not know how exactly the strings look like I cannot write a function accordingly.

Comment: You need to escape the character like \\t and \\n

Comment: You need in javascript the string /t and /n?

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(" \t when i want to do a console.log or a document.write \n more text "));`

Comment: @Pranay Well then I will have to use the replace() method then since I do not generate the string myself. A possible solution.

Comment: @AlexK. I will see if that solves the issue.